# Ubuntu terminal command to open window to CWD?

Tags: browser, terminal, nautilus

Is there a command to open a gui browser (not the web kind, the xwindows kind) to the current working directory in the terminal?

For example, I'm working in the terminal,

/im/in/some/dir/somewhere$ openthisdir

where openthisdir would open the nautilus browser to that particular place (CWD).

Answer (score 4):

That is exactly what I was going to suggest but the slash isn't necessary:

```
nautilus .
```

You can also use a program called gnome-open which works on all file types you have applications installed for in GNOME.

```
gnome-open .
gnome-open blah.avi
```

etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I figured out the answer as a result of formulating the question, about a half second after pushing submit.

There is indeed such a command,

```
/im/in/some/dir/somewhere$ nautilus ./
```

I love linux.